# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace rabbit JBOSS

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, rabbitmq

I want to run spring appp with jboss server but I faced this problem : Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit]

```
applicationcontext: 
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache
                        http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

dependecies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this dependency.**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.11</version>
</dependency>
```